# Is it possible to Redirect an HTTPPost in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, redirect, http-post

In my MVC application I have a View that collects user input in a basic Form.  When the user hits submit it Posts to my MVC Application where I perform a database operation but then need to redirect the values from the Form to an external URL via another HTTP Post.

The real scenario is as follows.

1.
I display a Shopping Cart Page.  The View contains an Html Form which contains financial details (ie. items, unit price, quanitities and a total).  As well it collects billing and shipping information.

2.
When the user hit the submit the Form values are included in a Post to my MVC Application.  At this point I need to record that a payment is about to be collected so I write an entry to my database.  Then I need to redirect to a third party site that will do the credit card processing.  This redirect must be an HTTP Post that includes the same Form Values from my original Form.

3.
The user will be presented with the third party credit card processing page.  It handles the redirect to me.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate http post request from controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705442/generate-http-post-request-from-controller)

Comment: I don't think so.  In that case the server makes the request and redirects to another action/view within the MVC Application.  I'm guessing they consume / process the result of the Http Post on the server.  In my case the client (ie. Browser) will render the response to the Http Post.

Answer (score 3):

You could make an Ajax call when the user first submits the form. The call would write to your database, return data (if needed) to the page, then the callback would post the page to the third party.

Comment: totally agreed this would work.  I've considered both that and having the server update the db and then redirect to a view that auto-submits a form on page load which performs a post to the payment page.  But both of these require an extra message or trip from the server to the client.  I guess there is no way around that.  I'll mark yours as the answer if I don't see a better solution over the next few days.  Thanks again for the suggestion.